# Get row HTML element based on grid's record/model in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a grid in ExtJS where I am looping store items. I'd like to find a find to access the item's HTML element, but I'm having hard time finding the way to do this.

Simply put: how do you find the corresponding row HTML element for grid store's one record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use its index in the store to retrieve the corresponding row, like so:

```
var htmlElement = grid.getView().getRow(index);
```

Comment: How about just getting the Element for the row, not the HTMLElement?

Comment: ah, var el = Ext.get(htmlElement); // d'oh! :)

Answer (score 2):

ExtJS 4.x: `grid.getView().getNode(index)`

[`getNode`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.view.AbstractView-method-getNode) can take an HTML ID (not very useful), an index, or a store record.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a little to it, if you've got a record that exists in a store that has a grid, but it came from say a separate ajax request, you might do

```
var objFromJSON: {
    id: 134,
    name: "Articulated Lorry"
}

var gridIndex = Ext.getStore("myStore").find("id", objFromJSON.id);
var htmlElement = grid.getView().getRow(gridIndex);
```